# Group by external data not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list-view

I have created an external data connection to an SQL DB using SharePoint designer 2013 to pull out our client list, I then created a list with all the clients, I then created a site column to be able to use the client name in the site and subsite

For some reason when I try to group by client I get the following error?

[image]

Here are two things related to the ID and webparts

> InnerException 1: System.ArgumentException: The control must be in the
>   control tree of a page.  Parameter name: control     at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control
>   control, Type type, String key, String url)

and this one

> Error while executing web part: System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException:
>   An error occurred during a call to extension function
>   'RegisterScriptLink'. See InnerException for a complete description of
>   the error. ---> System.ArgumentException: The control must be in the
>   control tree of a page.  Parameter name: control      at
>   System.Web.UI.ScriptRegistrationManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control
>   control, Type type, String key, String url)     -  -- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlExtensionFunction.Invoke(Object extObj,
>   Object[] args)      at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.InvokeXsltLateBoundFunction(String
>   name, String namespaceUri, IList`1[] args)      at (XmlQueryRuntime
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)      at (XmlQueryRuntime
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current, String
>   ShowSelectAllCheckbox)      at (XmlQueryRuntime
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)      at
>   Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
>   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument,
>   XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ApplyXslTransform(XPathNavigator
>   dataNavigator, XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform,
>   XsltArgumentList xmlArguments)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.ExecuteTransform(XslCompiledTransform
>   xslCompiledTransform, XsltArgumentList xmlArguments, Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

Comment: Get the correlation ID and look into the log files via SharePoint ULS Log Viewer, you need to get the complete error details

Comment: Which log file do I need to check in this location? C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

Comment: Try to regenerate the error and get the latest file.. It logs the error in the latest file as soon as it appears

Comment: I have found two things, please see my question at the top, thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK so the only way I can get this to work is to create a calculated column based on the external data column, then group using the calculated column

I have marked this as answer just in case another else has this issue